# Print the line if it contains a specific word (C++)

Tags: c++, getline

I noticed a user had a similar question, but they were writing in python and I'm trying to figure out a c++ solution.

I'm currently writing a spell checker and I'm trying print the line from a file if it contains a specific string. I though the `getline()` function would be useful for a solution, but I'm not too sure how to use it in my case.

```
 ifstream inputFileIn(inputFilename);
  list inputFile;
  string word;
  while (inputFileIn >> word)
    {
      transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower); //convert words to lowercase to spellcheck

      //remove punctuation from the word
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
          if (ispunct(word[i]))
            {
              word.erase(i--, 1);       
            }
        }

      //if spelled incorrectly 
      if (!wordList.contains(word) && std::string::npos == word.find_first_of("0123456789,:;.!?-() ") && word != "\n")
        {
          inputFile.add(word, 0);
        }
    }
```

So if `word` was in the line, it would print out all other words that share that line. I'm not really looking for someone to do it, but I need some clarity as to how I could use `getline()`

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the responses. I'm currently using this

```
      if (!wordList.contains(word) && std::string::npos == word.find_first_of("0123456789,:;.!?-() ") && word != "\n")
        {
          string line;
          while (getline(inputFileIn, line))
            {
              if (line.find(word))
                {         
                  cout << "Line is: " << line << '\n' << "Word is: " << word << endl;
                }
            }
          inputFile.add(word, 0);
        }
    }
```

For some reason though, `if (line.find(word))` is always returning true, even if I do `if (line.find("....."))` which is clearly not contained in the line.

Comment: Use `getline` to get a string, then use [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use `getline` to read a line at a time:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(inputFileIn, line))
{
    ...
```

To check for a particular word, if you want to check word boundaries, ignore case and punctuation, cope with hyphenated words and other oddities you'd probably find it easiest to use [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to extract each word, then see if they're in your wordlist.  Otherwise, if your wordlist is short you can search for each entry in the line in turn with [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), but if the wordlist is long that will be inefficient and you'll want to extract candidate words from the line.  That can be done crudely with:

```
std::istringstream iss{line};
while (line >> word)
{
    ...transform / remove punctuation etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've used that while loop and find(), but for some reason the if statement always returns true. I've updated the OG post with the problem.

Comment: You should have read the linked doco and examples for find ;-P.  It doesn't return a boolean, but the offset into the string at which the substring is found, or a special sentinel value `npos` ("no position") if the substring isn't found.  Your if needs to check that `find` doesn't return `npos`.